# why my unit test project is not using proper appsettings.Test.json when appsettings.json contains placeholders?

Tags: .net-core, xunit, appsettings

I have a dotnet core 6 solution. In my API project I have set the appsettings.json to have some placeholders, like that:

```cs
"Host": #{Logging__StdLog__QueueSettings__Host}#,
        "Port": #{Logging__StdLog__QueueSettings__Port}#,
        "Username": #{Logging__StdLog__QueueSettings__Username}#,
        "Password": #{Logging__StdLog__QueueSettings__Password}#,
```

This is necessary, since we need to substitute these values in various pipeline environments, so I have set up my unit test project to use another file for settings, I have called it appsettings.Test.json, very creative, I know.
What I've noticed is that when i run my unit tests I receive the obvious exception

```cs
System.IO.InvalidDataException : Failed to load configuration from file 'C:\MyWorkDir\MySolution\MyProject.UnitTest\bin\Debug\net6.0\appsettings.json'.
---- System.FormatException : Could not parse the JSON file.
-------- System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException : '#' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 44 | BytePositionInLine: 16.
```

which is not so obvious considering that in the Unit Test project's program.cs I stated clearly that I want to use appsettings.Test.json:

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
    builder.Host.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
    });
    var controllersAssembly = Assembly.Load("MyAPIProject");
    builder.Services
        .AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddApplicationPart(controllersAssembly);
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Test.json");
    builder.Services.AddCommonOptions(configuration);
    builder.Services.AddProblemDetailsFactories();
    builder.Services.AddResultFactories();
    builder.Services.AddRepositories(configuration);
    builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    builder.Services.AddLoggingProducer(configuration, excludeEFLogger: true);
    builder.Services.AddTraceProducer<TraceMessageProducer>(configuration);

    var app = builder.Build();
    app.UseMockServerVariables();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    app.UseActivityMiddleware(true);
    app.Run();

}
```

and that the file appsettings.json isn't even in that project.

I tried everything I know, but my tests keep trying to use appsettings.json file.
Then I tried with a change in appsettings.json, simply temporarily eliminating placeholders, putting those values to null. This way, Unit Tests are pointing to the correct appsettings.Test.json.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

`appsettings.json` is in your test project output directory (`MyProject.UnitTest\bin\Debug\net6.0\`) because your test project references the API project and the API project probably has specified in the `.csproj` that `appsettings.json` gets copied to the output folder.

Did you check if in your test project output dir you also have your `appsettings.Test.json` file?
If not, you would need to configure your test project so that the test file gets copied to the output folder, in order to be able to be used.

Otherwise, `WebApplication.CreateBuilder()` adds the default configuration, which includes adding the config from `appsettings.json` file.

I'm not sure right now how that `ConfigurationManager` works, but the way `ConfigurationBuilder` does is the latter you add a configuration, the more priority it has, i.e. this is how you would configure it properly:

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

You want to aim to do the same: apply `appsettings.Test.json` after the defaults introduce by `WebApplication.CreateBuilder()` so that the former gets used.